# Should we write catch(Exception e) for every try catch block in java

Tags: java, exception, try-catch

My question is should we have `catch(Exception e)` for every try - catch block. Knowing that it will catch all exceptions .... is this type of coding recommended in java or should i only catch exceptions that are known to occur.

Consider the below example.

```
 try {
     //something
 } catch (NumberFormatException ne) {
     //do something
 } catch (Exception e) {
     log.error(e);
 }
```

Comment: *should i only catch exceptions that are known to occur.* Only catch what you want to handle. Other exceptions might still occur.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. This is not a good practice. Identify exceptions that will be thrown before implementation. Catch only those exceptions that you are throwing from your method.

Thoroughly unit test your code and identify them.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. you can keep multiple catch for one try. But the hierarchy should be more specific to generic type.

Also i totally agreed sith Tejas's answer.